# Jack Audio application won't start under pipewire

Tags: jack, pipewire

Jack applications are refusing to make sound. For example, trying to sart the SuperCollider server gets the error `ATTENTION: The playback device "hw:PCH" is already in use. Please stop the application using it and run JACK again`

This worked fine until recently on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new(?) package required for Jack apps, pipewire-jack

`sudo apt-get install pipewire-jack`

You may need to reboot pipewire before this will work.

`systemctl --user restart pipewire-media-session`

This should fix it.

Comment: Has pipewire-jack been discontinued? Just tried to install it and it's not in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make this work, but it seems over complicated.

You need to start your app with

> pw-jack your-app

This redirects libjack to the pipe wire version.
This is highly unsatisfactory, and for example does not work with snap applications.

It should be a system wide selection.